# Two Navigation With MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

I want to add a navigation bar inside my views to move to sub-view.

However, when I change the side menu bar selected item nothing show.

Here is the project source code:

https://github.com/markoshenoda/NeedHelp.git

I tried DataTemplate in app.xaml:

```xml
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AddPepoleViewModel}">
        <v:AddPepoleView />
    </DataTemplate>
    
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PepoleHomeViewModel}">
        <v:PepoleHomeView />
    </DataTemplate>
```

and also in the people view:

```xml
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AddPepoleViewModel}">
           <local:AddPepoleView />
        </DataTemplate>
    
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PepoleHomeViewModel}">
            <local:PepoleHomeView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Well, https://github.com (or other version control site) is a perfect place for publishing source code. A zip-container on any filehoster is not

Comment: As a relatively unimportant remark: it looks to me as if you misspelled the word "people" like for example in your *`View` and *`ViewModel` names, e.g. "AddPepoleViewModel", "AddPepoleView", "PepoleHomeViewModel", "PepoleHomeView". So that the SO readers, or you yourself in the future would perhaps get irritated a little...

Comment: i upload it in github

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in Pepole View

```
<ContentControl
                Grid.Column="1"
                DataContext="{Binding SideNaveer.SelectedView}"
                RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"/>
```

and The correct is

```
<ContentControl
                Grid.Column="1"
                Content="{Binding SideNaveer.SelectedView}"
                RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"/>
```